# Seeking web page or small install GIS client to test WMS URL

Tags: wms, software-recommendations

I am using JMP 9, which supports WMS maps (as a client), but it doesn't seem to be working now.

Is there a web based, or small install GIS client on which I can test a WMS URL?

To clarify, I was looking for something that would help me find out the correct querystring parameters to send, as the service I was hoping to use did not specify them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to check your WMS with the firefox plug-in - "WMS Inspector" - see github page https://github.com/amercader/WMS-Inspector/wiki

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy way to do this would be using jsfiddle. You can just load the javascript mapping library of your choice and do a let more than just test the WMS URL.

This is using Leaflet. Just replace the WMS url with your own and click 'Run'
http://jsfiddle.net/tmoy0f0g/1/

Answer (score 1):

I use [Gaia](http://www.thecarbonproject.com/Products/Gaia):

> Gaia is a platform designed for advanced geospatial network and SDI
>   needs. Based on the CarbonTools PRO open-geospatial development
>   toolkit, this viewer can access an array of geospatial sources such as
>   the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Web Mapping Service (WMS), Web
>   Map Tile Service (WMTS), Web Coverage Service (WCS), Web Feature
>   Service (WFS), and Filter Encoding (FE), services such as Microsoft
>   Bing Maps, Yahoo! Maps and OpenStreetMap (OSM), as well as file
>   formats such as ESRI Shapefiles, Google Earth KML/KMZ, DXF, MIF,
>   Geography Markup Language (GML) and GML Simple Features (GMLsf).

Answer (score 1):

A new (as of 2023) tool to do this is https://ows.mapserverstudio.net/ (disclaimer I am the author).

OWS Inspector is a JavaScript web application for testing Open Web Service requests (such as WMS) against geospatial servers.
It is open source with code available at https://github.com/geographika/ows-inspector

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear whether you are interested in testing whether JMP9 can consume a WMS properly, or whether it can act as a WMS server.

If you want to test if your software can act as a WMS client, you can point it to a service like one of the services at MassGIS:  https://wiki.state.ma.us/confluence/display/massgis/Home

If you want to test if your software can act as a WMS Server, you can simply make a WMS request to your software from a Web Browser.  Using a desktop client like QGIS would even be easier.