# Somebody knows a test to my application using WMS 1.1 (as a client) with OGC Standard?

Tags: open-source-gis

I need a test to certificate my application with the OGC Standard. Please if somebody knows a site or something in which i can do this please contact me or answer this topic.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Is your program a WMS client or a server?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about a server then you'll want to look at http://www.opengeospatial.org/compliance - especially the section on CITE tests.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ArcGIS installed?  You can add WMS layers as a datasource.  I think its safe to say if it works in ArcGIS that it meets the OGC specs.

If you dont have ArcGIS installed, there are a number of free WMS clients out there.  Off the top of my head, I know uDig is a good one.  Check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/is-there-a-web-page-where-i-can-test-a-wms-url) post as well.

Comment: Testing that it works in a particular WMS client doesn't test that it meets the entire OGC spec. The WMS client might only use part of the spec (e.g. not request all the advertised image types) or it might be forgiving of minor violations of the spec.