# is there any online WFS gazeteer client which runs on my web browser or exposes http requests?

Tags: javascript, wfs, xml, gazetteer, client

My question is somehow similar to this other thread, but in my case I want to test a WFS service:

[Is there a web page where I can test a WMS URL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/is-there-a-web-page-where-i-can-test-a-wms-url)

I look for an online service which lets me add the url of a WFS gazetter service, and then exposes the layers and features available and lets me make filtered requests to that gazetter (i.e. look for a place name) using a web interface.

I am particularly interested in javascript implementations which do actually make WFS requests from my browser, since the final purpose is to expose the underlying http request sent to the WFS server.

In other words: I am tired of trying to construct the right requests on my own. I am not being able to adapt requests from documentation and examples (there are many differences between WFS versions, namespaces, and so on ...)

Comment: You could use something like QGIS and Fiddler in combination to look at HTTP requests to your WFS service.  You need to ensure that you only download features that are within a bounding box, or else you will only see one request (the initial request to get all the data), this is different from a WMS, where every request in your client is converted to a request to the server.